# Editing a text area with a form

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm working on a little web app and as part of it, I need to get a form to edit some code in a text area by overwriting identifiers like %name% and %slogan% with real values like Jeremy and Interface Designer.

Here's the code I've got at the moment. It just changes all the values on load to the specified text, but I want it to change it after the user has submitted the form and entered text into input fields.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').each(function(index, element) {
       var textarea = $(element);
       textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/%name%/, 'Victor Erixon'));
    });
});
```

It **must** be done with jQuery.

Let me know if you can code it.

Comment: I would change the regex from `/%name%/` to `/%name%/g` to replace all matching identifiers and not only the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the website you provided in the comments, I made the script fit your needs and elements:

*I recommend setting `disabled="disabled"` on the final code textarea, so the users can select, but cannot edit the content*

```
<form method="get">
    <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Victor Erixon"/></label><br/>
    <label for="slogan">Slogan: <input type="text" id="slogan" placeholder="Interface Designer"/></label><br/>
    <label for="bio">Bio: </label><br>
    <textarea id="bio" placeholder="Write something about yourself"></textarea><br/>
    <label for="favicon">Favicon: <input type="text" id="favicon" placeholder="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b20f810469b0.png"/></label><br/>
    <label for="dribble">Dribble: <input type="text" id="dribble" placeholder="victorerixon"/></label><br/>
    <textarea class="code" disabled="disabled"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

```
var basicHtml = '<html>\n   <head>\n        <title>%name%</title>\n     <meta name="description" content="%bio%">\n     <link rel="icon" href="%favicon%">\n    </head>\n   <body>\n        <h1>%name%</h1>\n       <h2>%slogan%</h2>\n     <ul id="portfolio">%dribbble%</ul>\n        <p class="about">%bio%</p>\n    </body>\n</html>';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.code').val(basicHtml);

    $('form').on('submit',function() {
        var content = basicHtml;
        content = content.replace(/%name%/g, ($('#name').val()||$('#name').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%slogan%/g, ($('#slogan').val()||$('#slogan').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%bio%/g, ($('#bio').val()||$('#bio').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%favicon%/g, ($('#favicon').val()||$('#favicon').attr('placeholder')));
        var final = content.replace(/%dribble%/g, ($('#dribble').val()||$('#dribble').attr('placeholder')));
        $('.code').val(final);
        
        return false;
    }).on('reset',function(){
        $('form textarea:not(.code),form input').val();
        $('.code').val(basicHtml);
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/2fMKu/10/)</kbd>

---

### Without need to define the `basicHtml`:

You will always have to write the textarea's code like this: *(no space or tab between the opening/closing `<html>` and `<textarea>` tags)*

```
<textarea class="code" disabled="disabled"><html>
    <!-- rest of the code -->
</html></textarea>
```

and change the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var basicHtml = ($('.code').html()).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
    
    //rest of code
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/2fMKu/11/)</kbd>

Comment: And how would I get the words 'Victor Erixon' to come from a specific input field?

Comment: Is that all the jQuery code I need in the .js file? Because it still isn't working :S

Comment: @JeremyBlazé I would need a link to your site to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I will just publish it and then I can send you a link. I actually just realised, does my site need to be published for this to work? :S

Comment: @JeremyBlazé You did not replace `#name`, you have to change it to your needs. Now with the link, I'll create the full code for you, just let me edit.

Comment: What version of jQuery should I use with it?

Comment: I've updated the site with the changes but it still doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I've missed? The jQuery version maybe?

Comment: @JeremyBlazé Link to the jQuery file as `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`, also see my edit, it may fix your problem, and also add functionality for your reset button. **Don't forget to include the `return false` in the script**

Comment: Thanks! Works excellently! Just how do you get the global replace?

Comment: @JeremyBlazé Fixed. Also change to `method="get"` since some browsers tend to give alets on refresh which may be annoying.

Comment: Beautiful thanks! What was the thing at the top? I just need to know if I need to do that for all the code I ever put in that field. I will eventually be prettying up the field and offering themes instead of crappy old base codes.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without the basic HTML at the top? Because if I change the code that's there then I won't have to re-enter the js for it.

Comment: @JeremyBlazé The thing on the top is the default html code that will be inserted to the textbox and will be used later for replacement. You can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/ZpWwB/) to create the string to use there from your new code whenever you want to update.

Comment: There actually is a way, let me make a fiddle for that too.

Comment: @JeremyBlazé Updated. If you ever need further assistance, feel free to contact me via skype: `guzsik.david`.

Comment: @JeremyBlazé Glad I could help. Don't forget to replace the `method="post"` with `method="get"`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use form [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event instead of document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formId').submit(function() {
        $('textarea').each(function(index, element) {
           var textarea = $(element);
           textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/%name%/, 'Victor Erixon'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It hasn't worked. Is there something I have to add to the form? I *have* changed the formID by using `<form id="formId">`. Is that right? Or is there something I have to do to the submit button?

Comment: You do not have to do with button if it is of type submit, just bind it with document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use form submit, but point the onclick of the submit button to your javascript function
2. validate the imput fields using the just called function
3. use the called function to do the replacing like your codes shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the code in the form.submit event;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('form').on('submit', function() {
        $('textarea').each(function(index, element) {
            var textarea = $(element);
            textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/%name%/, 'Victor Erixon'));
        });
   }); 
});
```